# How should I wait for component rerender in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, storybook

I have a component which is used to input some data with specific format. This data may present in one of two patterns, and that depends on how many characters have been entered. While the number of characters is equal to or less than 11 I set one mask `onKeyDown`, and upon entering one more character, I `setMask()` to the other pattern `onKeyDown`.

Now to the problem itself, this works perfectly on human interaction, but when I try the code below (inside a Storybook story `play` function) the 12th number typed makes the mask change but does not appear in my input, making my test break. How may I code my test so that it inputs the value correctly? Or is it bad code in my component?

The test:

```
export const CNPJTaxId: Story = {
  args: {
    name: 'cnpj',
    label: 'CNPJ',
  },
  render: Render,
  play: async ({ canvasElement }) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);

    await userEvent.type(
      canvas.getByLabelText('CNPJ'),
      '12345678000195',
      { delay: 125 }
    );
    await userEvent.click(canvas.getByRole('button'));
    expect(canvas.getByText(/12345678000195/gi)).toBeTruthy();
  },
}
```

Relevant events from my component:

```
  const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.key.match(/^\d$/) || event.code === 'Backspace') {
      const currLength = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').length;
      if (currLength === 11 && event.nativeEvent.key.match(/^\d$/)) {
        setMask(TAX_ID_MASK.CNPJ);
      } else if (currLength === 12 && event.code === 'Backspace') {
        setMask(TAX_ID_MASK.CPF);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  };

  const handleKeyUp = (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const currLength = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').length;
    if (currLength === 11 && event.code === 'Delete') {
      setMask(TAX_ID_MASK.CPF);
    }
  };
```